# Deserialize Avro message with schema type as object

Tags: apache-kafka, deserialization, kafka-consumer-api, avro

I'm reading from a Kafka topic, which contains Avro messages. I have given below schema.
I'm unable to parse the schema and deserialize the message.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Request",
  "namespace": "com.sk.avro.model",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "empId",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null,
      "description": "REQUIRED "
    },
    {
      "name": "carUnit",
      "type": "com.example.CarUnit",
      "default": "ABC",
      "description": "Car id"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting below error :

```
The type of the "carUnit" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression
```

Can anyone please help out.

Comment: Can you share the definition for `com.example.BusinessUnit`?

Comment: I have similar sub objects in the main Request.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous , Can you please guid me deserialise the message.
Can you also provide any ref links for avro message producer and consumer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
{
    "name": "businessUnit",
    "type": { 
        "type": { 
            "type": "record ", 
            "name": "BusinessUnit ", 
            "fields": [{ 
                "name": "hostName ", 
                "type": "string " 
             }] 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Can we have something like generic record if we don't have the definition of each type. Can you please provide me the code snippet to create generic record to parse the schema

Comment: @SreenivasK Avro is meant to be strictly typed. The most generic you can get is a `map` record